# how to convert data into table excel with python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

i have data that is displayed like that :

**Name1 : Name1 - {'Name1.1': ('data1', data2,data3), 'Name1.2': ('data1', data2,data3)}**

**Name2 : Name2 - {'Name2.1': ('data1', data2,data3)}**

**Name3 : Name3 - {'Name3.1': ('data1', data2,data3), 'Name3.2': ('data1', data2,data3),'Name3.3': ('data1', data2,data3)}**

i want to convert it into table excel to that form :
[image]

i have tried many combinations but i failed as i still a beginner can anyone help ? thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean with "displayed like that", that is not a valid python data storage format. You also said you tried manny things, please show at least the most promising approach you tried so far.

Comment: Please explain clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Andreas I'm listing data like that with "print("{} : {} - {}".format(name1, name2, data))" and the data is "data[name]=data1,data2,data3"

Comment: Please try to provide a good sample: [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) otherwise it will take longer fror us to reproduce your problem then to actually solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to improve your input you could get close:

**Example:**

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

# string as given is not valid...
s = '''
Name1 : Name1 - {'Name1.1': ('data1', data2,data3), 'Name1.2': ('data1', 'data2','data3')}
Name2 : Name2 - {'Name2.1': ('data1', data2,data3)}
Name3 : Name3 - {'Name3.1': ('data1', data2,data3), 'Name3.2': ('data1', 'data2','data3'),'Name3.3': ('data1', 'data2','data3')}
'''


# valid as all the dataX strings are in quotes...
s = '''
Name1 : Name1 - {'Name1.1': ('data1', 'data2','data3'), 'Name1.2': ('data1', 'data2','data3')}
Name2 : Name2 - {'Name2.1': ('data1', 'data2','data3')}
Name3 : Name3 - {'Name3.1': ('data1', 'data2','data3'), 'Name3.2': ('data1', 'data2','data3'),'Name3.3': ('data1', 'data2','data3')}
'''


ds = []

for l in s.splitlines():
    d = l.split('-')
    if len(d) > 1:
        df = pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(d[1].strip()))
        ds.append(df)
        
for df in ds:
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df = pd.concat(ds, axis= 1)

cols = df.columns

cols = [((col.split('.')[0], col)) for col in df.columns]

df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)

print(df.T)

                   0      1      2
Name1 Name1.1  data1  data2  data3
      Name1.2  data1  data2  data3
Name2 Name2.1  data1  data2  data3
Name3 Name3.1  data1  data2  data3
      Name3.2  data1  data2  data3
      Name3.3  data1  data2  data3
```

[image]

Comment: please how do i fix the probleme that he is not displaying name1,name2 ... ?? for more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68962900/how-to-put-data-into-table-with-pandas) on the question