# how to solve "If using all scalar values, you must pass an index" problem pandas

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, indexing, scalar

Following my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68962900/how-to-put-data-into-excel-table-with-for-loop-pandas) , all is working well but when the list it's long it's showing this erreur,
This is  a simple of d :

```
['Houda Golf & Aquapark Novostar Monastir ', " {'All Inclusive soft': ('202', '175', '15%'), 'Demi Pension': ('161', '140', '15%'), 'Petit Dejeuner': ('137', '119', '15%'), 'DP plus': ('237', '119', '15%')}"]
```

Anyone knows how can i fix it ? thank you in advance.

NB: I've tried several solutions from responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839973/constructing-pandas-dataframe-from-values-in-variables-gives-valueerror-if-usi) but they hasn't work for me

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert the values of dictionary to `list` if they are scalars:

```py
from ast import literal_eval


vals = literal_eval(d[1].strip())
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {k: v if isinstance(v, (list, tuple)) else [v] for k, v in vals.items()}
)
print(df)
```